# Decompile app IOS to get source code - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have an app that I need to get the source code to update the app. Customer doesn't have source code, only the app file from apple store. Is there any tool or method to get it?

Thanks

Comment: Just contact the developers. I'd say if you were reasonable with them, you might be able to get it for a lot less hassle than with a tool like IDA pro.

Comment: Besides, you may only be able to get the assembly code, not the original source code.

Comment: What was your customer's contractual relationship with the original developer?  Presumably the contract spelled out how the source code was to be handled.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. My question is because previous developer didn't perform the project in a professional way, the source code was not provided.

Comment: Professional or contractual way? Who has intellectual rights over the source code?

Comment: I am pretty sure it is your customer's fault. Submitting an application with your company's name without having the source code is dangerous. What if the original developer left some backdoor or malicious code? Not having the possibility to review source code can destroy a company (or at least its name) easily.

Comment: This customer is dangerous. Run away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot decompile an iOS app to get the source code. Once it is submitted to the store, even the dSYM file is stripped, so errors don't provide the source code context. I'm afraid you are out of luck.

As @Richard J. Ross III has mentioned, there are tools that may help you get the assembly, but you will never be able to get the actual source code back. Depending on the detail of the app, you may just want to rewrite the application.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. So I assume there's no way to get source code back, I heard from colleagues that work for Apple that it's possible to do it, but I can not find any solution in the net.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0RLoNRmvT3Q
P.S: I found it on the internet, it's not mine.