# Secure public api for mobile app with laravel

Tags: laravel, api, authentication

I Guys, i have to create a mobile app that need to make a request to a laravel endpoint, app no require registration or login, which is the best way to protect my api? To make sure the only my application can call it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no full proof method of securing your api, because with the right tools and following some tutorials on the web, anyone could view your whole api request, headers, tokens, etc.

Anything you do or store on the app is already compromised, so [signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22774724/4516316),ssl, encryption,tokens, etc are not that helpful if malicious users have access to the app. It can make it more troublesome for malicious users, but a dedicated one could overcome it.

Using authentication atleast forces users to register before they can use your api and you can block the user when needed. Along with requiring email verification, users who wish to misuse your api would then need valid email addresses atleast. But since you mention securing without authentication, this goes out of scope.

You can secure your api somewhat by using rate limiting. laravel has an inbuilt rate limiting with the throttle middleware. You can use this to restrict the number of times an api can be called in a particular time interval by an ip address.

Next would be Ip blocking. If any malicious activity is found, you could block the ip address. But this can be overcome with a vpn, and a malicious user could also block someone elses ip in this manner.

Captcha can help against bots, but would also annoy regular users.

Another method would be restriction with cors, those who have faced cors issues know exactly how annoying it can be, but it wont work on native apps (or you could try [pwa](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/)).

And in a worse case scenario you could go with some terms and conditions and some legal action

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution You can create a table for devices with api key which will be generated for each device app, and always use it to send requests to the api end point, then used it to fetch data from the rest api. The same process like if you are loging in, but you will use the api key unstead and the key will be fixe not refreshed evrey time.